# french string econded give errors when is printed

Tags: php, string, utf-8, french

I've this string encoded on a lang file:

```
&#201;quipe de r&#233;f&#233;rence
```

if is printed straight is not conveted to the right syntax, and is the same as the above:

> Équipe de référence

So I have added an:

```
html_entity_decode();
```

and on my linux, libreoffice and open as downloaded CSV works too.

But If I open it on windows/mac text editor or Excel is printed like:

> √âquipe de r√©f√©rence

All is UTF8 encoded, so I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

The question is not about "open a file correctly", is about encoded string and how to print them correctly.

So for example, adding:

```
if you want make UTF-8 file for excel, use this:

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
```

[the code above source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Just curious, why would you have it as &#201;quipe de r&#233;f&#233;rence in the lang file? I mean, why it isn't stored as Équipe de référence already?

Comment: @YourCommonSense i dont know about that! I think is related about some other function of the app... Actually Im working on other piece of code of this, and I take it, as is it. This question was closed, but is not about "how to open a file corretcly" but how to save it in right string format

Comment: But your string is already printed correctly? while your problem is how to make some certain software to open this file. And the linked answer explains exactly that, the BOM solution included

Comment: In the end the question _is_ about how to *open* the file correctly. The file is already in the right format! (Probably, double check with a hex editor whether it contains the right bytes.) The issue is that some programs—especially Excel—don't know what the "right encoding" is and simply interpret the file in the wrong encoding. Adding a leading BOM _can_ help, but isn't a guarantee that they'll get it right.